# Logarithms - How to handle factors within a difference or sum term of logarithms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

**Edit:** I just rewrote the whole question, to make it clear, what I'm looking for. Originally I asked about solving $16^{x+1} = 4^{x+3}$, then corrected it to $16^{x+2} = 4^{x+3}$.

But what I really want to know is this: How do you get from

> $$(x + 2)\ln(16) - (x + 3)\ln(4) = \ln(1)$$

to

> $$x = \frac{3\ln(4) - 2\ln(16)}{\ln(16) - \ln(4)}$$

I'm particularly concerned about the factors $(x+2)$ and $(x+3)$ as I don't understand, how they lead up the the last term above.

Comment: Multiply everything out, then group any term with an $x$.  Remember than $\ln 1 = 0$.

Comment: You know that $(x+1)\ln 16 = x\ln 16 + 1\ln 16$, right?

Comment: Why are you using logarithm ? However if you want to use it in a appropriated basis.

Comment: Because I'm learning how to calculate with logarithms.

Comment: If you edit the question to make a correction, please mention that you've done so in the question, so that people understand why the answers are all now wrong.

Comment: Reformed the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I suggested an edit that makes it clear where the existing answers are coming from, just an idea.

Comment: Ah, thanks, need to get up to standards.

Comment: I'm not particularly advocating standards, just trying to make the whole page make sense when you visit it the first time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've got $(x+2)\ln(16)−(x+3)\ln(4)=\ln(1)$, use $\log 1 = 0$ (true regardless of the base) and then forget about the logs entirely for now: the rest is just algebra, so let $a = \ln(16)$ and $b = \ln(4)$. Then solve $$(x+2)a - (x+3)b = 0$$ for $x$, by expanding the brackets and rearranging; you will get $$x = \frac{3b - 2a}{a - b}$$, which is indeed (substituting back in $a$ and $b$) exactly what you wanted.

(If you can't do the algebra, say so and I'll give a bit more detail).

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense. I got too focused on the logs and somehow fumbled over the whole equation.

Answer (score 4):

To proceed with what you have done, you need to recognize that $\ln(1) = 0$ and $\ln(a^b) = b \times \ln(a)$ i.e. $\ln(16) = \ln(4^2) = 2 \ln(4)$. Then you can simplify the expression you have to get
$$(x+2) \times 2 \times \ln(4) - (x+3) \times \ln(4) = 0$$ i.e.
\begin{align*}
(x+2) \times 2 \times \ln(4) &= (x+3) \times \ln(4) \\
2(x+2) &= x+3 \\
2x+4 &= x +3 \\
x&=-1
\end{align*}

The easier way is to take the logarithm to the base $4$. Then we get that $$(x+2) \times \log_4(16) = (x+3) \times \log_4(4)$$
Hence, 
\begin{align*}
(x+2) \times \log_4(4^2) &= (x+3) \times 1 \\
(x+2) \times 2 \times \log_4(4) &= (x+3) \times 1 \\
(x+2) \times 2 \times 1 &= (x+3) \times 1 \\
2x+4 &= x+3 \\
x&=-1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

Why would you apply logarithms before simplifying stuff??

$16^{x+1}=4^{x+3}\Longrightarrow \left((2^4)\right)^{x+1}=\left(2^2\right)^{x+3}\Longrightarrow 2^{4x+4}=2^{2x+6}\Longrightarrow 4x+4=2x+6\Longrightarrow x=1$

Comment: Well, uh, it's about learning logarithms. The solution of $x$ was marked as $-1$, is this wrong?

Comment: @MiroslavCetojevic Yes $x=-1$ is indeed wrong. You can check this by plugging in the value $x=-1$ to get the incorrect statement that $16^{-1+1} = 4^{-1+3}$

Comment: Of course it is wrong! $,1=16^0=16^{-1+1}\neq 4^{-1+2}=4^2=16$